# Regex to get the [nth] name following a specific set of text

Tags: regex

I don't have a great grasp on Regex; but I am attempting to grab names following the word "sortname", but only after the nth time that word appears.

I have (thanks to Wikipedia's API) a list of governors in the United States, listed in order of their states name alphabetically. (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=wikitext&page=List_of_current_United_States_governors&section=1&format=json)

If you do ctrl+f you will see that each name follows the word "sortname" and there are 50 of them. So if I wanted to see who the Governor of Texas is, I would get the name that follows the 43rd instance of the word "sortname". furthermore the first and last name of each governor is formatted as "sortname|Kay|Ivey" or "sortname|Michelle|Lujan Grisham".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: and what have u tried so far?

Comment: [\n\r][ \t]*sortname[ \t]*([^\n\r]*) but cant get it to work

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing I have ended up with the following pattern sortname([^;]*)[^}|]}

It collects more than necessary but its going in the right direction. I can use python to sort it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a string `str` contains the whole text, would you please try:

```
m = re.findall(r'sortname\|[^|]+\|[^}]+', str, re.DOTALL)
print(m[42])
```

Output:

```
sortname|Greg|Abbott
```